# How to make a login page view xcode navigation and tabbar controller push pop views

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I've tried many different ways but can't get it to work. How can I make a simple login/logout view/app? I need the initial page to be a regular UITableView, once login button is pressed it should (push/addsubview ?) to a new UITabBarView (with 2 UITableViews in that), on the second tab exists a logout button, which should send you back to initial login page, also on the login page the nav controller and tabbar should never show up, (but I think I can figure that out). I tried pushing and popping viewcontrollers put that's getting messy. Xcode 4.1

Examples or help will keep me from pulling the little hair I have left out!
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I 've wrote some thing, may be it took complex to understand by you but i've tried to explain, main theme is that to make a navigation controller and set it to app delegate window's root view controller then push login view controller to it, and then pushing tabbar controller, read below some explanation.

this is mostly done by making a navigation controller and setting it the app delegate window's root view controller, then make a view controller that is your login view and setting it the root view controller to app delegate's navigation controller, then make a tabbar controller (a view controller) which contains tabbar and navigation controllers on each tabbaritem, and furhter each navigation controller has a reference to tabbar controller(the view controller pushed at login time). So, whenever logins is pressed, it pushes the tabbarcontroller and performs tasks. and when you want to logout, just pop to root view controller of the referenc's navigation controller which in fact is the login view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide tabbar, then show it after login success.

https://github.com/idevsoftware/Cocoa-Touch-Additions/tree/master/UITabBarController_setHidden